# item/image not sizing properly in bootstrap carousel at xs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to solve this issue with CSS, but is this technically a JS issue?

```
.carousel-inner .item {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner .item img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: none;
}
```

here are my media queries

```
/* Tablets an medium desktops */
@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
}
/* Tablets portrait and small desktops*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
}
/* landscape phones and portrait tablets */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}
/* landscape phones and small devices */
@media (max-width: 480px) and (height: 300px) {
}
```

Comment: new to this and even posting questions.  Please bare with me.

Comment: please, provide some examples on what is wrong